# Is it possible to pull tweets that has image or video only on twitter api?

Tags: java, android, api, twitter

I tried using twitter api on php, which is very basic pulling of public tweets. Now I am in the process of learning it on java and android with a twist which my code should pull or process tweets that has image or videos on it. I read the documentations of twitter api and searched for quite of time now, but so far I couldn't find good documentations, tutorials or examples on it.

Do you have any ideas how to do it? Or sample codes which you can share?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all tweets of your request, decode the redirector links (such as bit.ly) to get the actual links and then check for the domain (such as youtube.com or instagram.com). If you just want to show the tweet, you're fine but actually getting the image that the link points to is harder because you need to implement it for every single imagehoster you want to support.

To access to Twitter you can use Twitter4j. As far as I know it is not possible to get [native media previews](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/2.2.4/twitter4j-core-2.2.4-javadoc.jar!/twitter4j/Annotations.html) with Twitter4j (but you can use the links as described above).